# Convergence of a serie to a value

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, laurent-series

I have to prove that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n = \frac{1-\theta}{1-\theta z}$ for some $\theta\in (0,1]$, $z\in (0,1]$.

I know that $a_n \geq 0$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n=1$.

But hw can I choose $\theta$ ? And how can I get this equality ?

Comment: This is false, as the term on the left-hand side can be a polynomial, while the term on the right-hand side is not. Please add the missing information about $a_n$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $\theta$ depends on $z$. Given $z\in(0,1]$, let $A=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$. Then 
$$
A=\frac{1-\theta}{1-\theta\,z}\implies \theta=\frac{1-A}{1-A\,z}.
$$
Since $A,\theta\in(0,1]$, it follows that also $\theta\in(0,1]$.